# Emacs, nxhtml how to highlight or jump to the closing html tag?

Tags: emacs, nxhtml

I'm using emacs with **nxhtml** to edit my HTML files but I can't find out how to highlight or *jump to the closing* HTML tag?

It sounds like an easy and stupid question but i really can't find it. Maybe I'm not looking for the right thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use functions from `sgml-mode`:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> (`sgml-skip-tag-forward`)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (`sgml-skip-tag-backward`)

You can always remap them to more handy shortcut for your major mode, i.e.:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
 (define-key html-mode-map (kbd "<M-left>") 'sgml-skip-tag-backward)
 (define-key html-mode-map (kbd "<M-right>") 'sgml-skip-tag-forward)
 )
)
```

Answer (score 5):

In `nxhtml-mode`, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> should indicate the following bindings:

```
<C-M-down>  nxml-down-element
<C-M-left>  nxml-backward-element
<C-M-right> nxml-forward-element
<C-M-up>    nxml-backward-up-element
```

The forward and backward functions are what you're asking about, while the up and down functions let you move to the parent or child element in the hierarchy.

The `sgml-mode` answer is more robust for HTML (as opposed to well-formed XHTML), but you may want to add autoloads for those functions if you'll be using them in `nxhtml-mode`, as the latter does not require the former.

```
(autoload 'sgml-skip-tag-forward "sgml-mode"
  "Skip to end of tag or matching closing tag if present.
With prefix argument ARG, repeat this ARG times.
Return t if after a closing tag." t)

(autoload 'sgml-skip-tag-backward "sgml-mode"
  "Skip to beginning of tag or matching opening tag if present.
With prefix argument ARG, repeat this ARG times.
Return non-nil if we skipped over matched tags." t)
```